# How to upload a file through Apollo Server v4 and graphql-upload?

Tags: apollo-server, typegraphql, apollo-upload-client, graphql-upload

im using Apollo server v4 with expressjs and NEXTJS for my Frontend. What I want is to create a Mutation like uploadFile using **upload-graphql** to upload a file to my Backend Server.

[image: backend_server]

upload type

```js
export interface Upload {
    filename: string;
    mimetype: string;
    encoding: string;
    createReadStream: () => Stream;
  }
```

my mutation:

```js
@Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async uploadFile(
    @Arg("picture", () => GraphQLUpload)
    { createReadStream, filename }: Upload
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
      createReadStream()
        .pipe(createWriteStream(__dirname + `/../../../images/${filename}`))
        .on("finish", () => resolve(true))
        .on("error", () => reject(false))
    );
  }
}
```

but the problem is, whenever I upload something like a photo,
I get `ApolloError: Argument Validation Error` .

I think, there is no way to upload through new Version of Apollo server (v4) yet, but if anyone knows about it, please help me !

my dependencies

```json
"dependencies":{
   "@apollo/server": "^4.3.1",     
   "express": "^4.18.2",
   "graphql": "^16.6.0",     
   "graphql-fields": "^2.0.3",     
   "graphql-middleware": "^6.1.33",     
   "graphql-scalars": "^1.20.1",     
   "graphql-shield": "^7.6.5",     
   "graphql-upload": "14",     
   "type-graphql": "2.0.0-beta.1",   },
```

I tried to upload a file on my frontend nextjs - apollo-upload-client.

and front-end upload Scenario

[image]

[image: code_of_front_end]

[image: front-end-app-config]

It's just a *hobby project*, and **I know** there are **alternatives** to kind of use other approach to upload files => like extra endpoint api or using like s3, but I want to get my files uploaded through graphql.

Comment: Do you find a solution ? Since version 4 of @apollo/server uses by default "CSRF prevention feature" that's why you have to put the "Apollo-Require-Preflight" header into createUploadLink for it works.

Comment: No, actually I didn't find any solution. If you have any. Please provide a piece of code @NicoSan

Comment: Still nothing? I've upgraded to Apollo Server 4 and I'm having some issues like "Error: Unexpected end of form"

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here a piece of code based on your sources (not tested), but you should add "Apollo-Require-Preflight" header into createUploadLink for it works

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: createUploadLink({
         headers: {"Apollo-Require-Preflight": "true"},
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```